# How to change textBlock.Foreground color when FlipView changed? c# UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

I have a page with Grid, there are two textBlocks on it and a FlipView at the bottom

```
<Grid>

 <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="First"/>
 <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Text="Second"/>

 <FlipView x:Name="flipView">

  <RelativePanel Background="White">
   //PanelContent
  </RelativePanel>

  <ScrollViewer>
   //ScrollViewerContent
  </ScrollViewer>

 </FlipView>

</Grid>
```

I want to change txt1 text color, when RelativePanel at the FlipView is active, and the same with txt2, when ScrollViewer is active. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `RelativePanel` and `ScrollViewer` inside a FlipViewItem, and handle the `SelectionChanged` event of the flip view. Check the `SelectedIndex` of the flip view and change the Foreground according to the index.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to do that. Two of them using the `DataTriggerBehavior`:

---

**Option 1: Solution with VisualStates**

Add a `VisualStateGroup` containing two `VisualStates` to your `VisualStateManager`:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="RelativeSelected"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ScrollSelected">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="txt1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFB6700" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="txt2" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

and trigger them by calling a `GoToStateAction`:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior x:Name="RelativePanelSelectedTrigger" Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=flipView}" Value="0">
            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="RelativeSelected" />
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior x:Name="ScrollViewerSelectedTrigger" Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=flipView}" Value="1">
            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="ScrollSelected" />
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Here´s a complete sample:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior x:Name="RelativePanelSelectedTrigger" Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=flipView}" Value="0">
            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="RelativeSelected" />
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior x:Name="ScrollViewerSelectedTrigger" Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=flipView}" Value="1">
            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="ScrollSelected" />
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="RelativeSelected"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ScrollSelected">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="txt1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFB6700" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="txt2" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="First" Foreground="#FF0068FF"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Text="Second"/>

    <FlipView x:Name="flipView">

        <RelativePanel x:Name="relativePanel" Background="White">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RelativePanel is selected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </RelativePanel>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ScrollViewer is Selected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </FlipView>

</StackPanel>
```

---

**Option 2: Solution using ChangePropertyAction**
If you want to avoid creating `VisualStates` you can change the `Foreground`-property directly.

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior x:Name="RelativePanelSelectedTrigger" Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=flipView}" Value="0">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=txt1}" PropertyName="Foreground">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF1700FF"/>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=txt2}" PropertyName="Foreground">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior x:Name="ScrollViewerSelectedTrigger" Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=flipView}" Value="1">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=txt1}" PropertyName="Foreground">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=txt2}" PropertyName="Foreground">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF73E017"/>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding the background property of txt1 to the selected item of your flip view;

```
background = "{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=flipView, Converter={StaticResource ObjectTypeToColorConverter}}"
```

Then create a [converter class](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/) that takes the selected item, checks its type and returns the color you desire based on the type;

```
if(obj.getType() == (typeOf)RelativePanel) return color.red;
```